Docker hub push
I have created a Jenkins file and want to push my image to docker hub, but even after I logged in successfully, I can't able to push the image to dockerhub.
Pipeline console log :
I have already created a repo for my user harsha330 --> mocktest-frontend
sing the existing docker config file.Removing blacklisted property: auths$ docker login -u harshanaidu3330@gmail.com -p \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\* https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DEV-MOCKTEST-FRONTEND@tmp/ae92d71f-062a-4d71-961c-fe8ee4a52e78/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
\[Pipeline\] {
\[Pipeline\] sh


    + sudo docker push harsha3330/mocktest-frontend:master-25-date-2024-06-23-dev


The push refers to repository \[docker.io/harsha3330/mocktest-frontend\]
6cf5d659944c: Preparing
173593466f68: Preparing
d6a02b1dc1a3: Preparing
94516bbd5b7d: Preparing
e56bb9782a6c: Preparing
5092b6c74280: Preparing
3e214109dd04: Preparing
5080acfc4b83: Preparing
0fd716f781a0: Preparing
011b303988d2: Preparing
5080acfc4b83: Waiting
5092b6c74280: Waiting
3e214109dd04: Waiting
0fd716f781a0: Waiting
011b303988d2: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied

push command :

    sh "sudo docker build -f applications/mocktest-frontend/Dockerfile -t mocktest-frontend ."
    dockerImage = "harsha3330/mocktest-frontend:${env.FrontendBranch}-${BUILD_NUMBER}-date-${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}-dev"
    sh "sudo docker tag mocktest-frontend:latest ${dockerImage}"
    docker.withRegistry('https://index.docker.io/v1/', registryCredential)

 {
    sh "sudo docker push ${dockerImage}"
     
    
    }\

Tried with multiple registries, no one is working.

The sudo is probably doing exactly the wrong thing here.

i gave sudo right to jenkins ,but without sudo i am not able to run the command , it is not able to connect to daemon itself

What exactly works depends on how exactly Docker is installed. On Debian-based platforms, the users who are granted access belong to the docker group. On Red Hat etc, only root / sudoers can access Docker.
